# Notifying entities when entity state changes in Lagom

Tags: persistence, messaging, lagom

Assuming a Record entity, CreateRecord command and a RecordCreated event. I want to invoke some command on one or more other entities (in different modules). What would be the suggested approach to achieve this?

I was thinking about sending a message from the ReadSide handler of the Record entity, which could be received by corresponding service(s), which would convert it to a command and invoke on an entity.

EDIT, thanks @ignasi35: According to [Message Broker API](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/MessageBrokerApi.html) publishing of the messages could be possible with this code.

```
AggregateEventTag<RecordEvent> RECORD_EVENT_TAG = AggregateEventTag.of(RecordEvent.class); 

public Topic<RecordMessage> recordsTopic() {
    return TopicProducer.singleStreamWithOffset(offset -> {
        return persistentEntityRegistry
                .eventStream(RECORD_EVENT_TAG, offset)
                .map(this::convertEventToRecordMessage);
    });
}
```

Records are created, and corresponding events are persisted, but no messages are received by the following consumer:

```
@Singleton
public class RecordsConsumer {
    @Inject
    public RecordsConsumer(RecordService recordService){
        recordService.recordsTopic().subscribe()
            .atLeastOnce(Flow.fromFunction(this::displayMessage));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @monad, the [Broker API](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/MessageBrokerApi.html) does exactly what you need. It plugs _eventStream_ of the persistent entity to a topic producer publishing the events to kafka. Other services can the subscribe to that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it.

I ended up with a singleton service listening to RecordCreated events from PersistentEntityRegistry.eventStream. The service converts them to RecordMessage and exposes as a Topic (see my question above).

The issue with not receiving any enents from the exposed Topic was missing dependency to kafka-broker (strange that there was no warning about this, and the topic was just not exposed), in my case this was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
    <artifactId>lagom-javadsl-kafka-broker_2.12</artifactId>
</dependency>
```